# The Jordan form for 4x4 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form

Suppose that a 4x4 matrix $A$ has vectors $v_a,b_b,v_c,v_d$ that satisfy $$Av_a=v_c, Av_c=-v_a, \ \ Av_b=-2v_b,\ \ Av_d=-2v_d+3v_b.$$

I want to find the Jordan canonical form of $A$, and the matrix $P$ such that $A=PJP^{-1}.$

I feel the question is ambiguous because when saying $A$ has vectors $v_a,b_b,v_c,v_d$ such that ... does it mean that $A's$ columns or rows consist of those vectors or $A$ is a matrix which is unknown but satisfies those condition above. So I am really greatful fo any help or hints

Comment: Does the exercise state that the vectors $v_a,v_b,v_c,v_d$ are linearly independent? Otherwise you can't obtain the Jordan form from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means exactly what it says, not more and not less. In matrix notation that gives
$$
A[v_a,v_c,v_b,v_d]=
[v_a,v_c,v_b,v_d]
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1&0&0\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&0&-2&3\\
0&0&0&-2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
In this form the task of identifying the Jordan normal form is greatly reduced. The transformation matrix has to use the basis matrix $V=[v_a,v_c,v_b,v_d]$ with the unidentified column vectors of the basis used.

Answer (score 3):

the given relations mean that, in the basis $\mathbf V=\{v_a,v_b,v_c,v_d\}$ (the vectors must be linearly independent) The linear transformation $A$ is represented by the matrix 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&-1&0\\
0&-2&0&3\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&-2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Remember that **in that basis $\mathbf V$** the vectors are represented as $v_a=[1,0,0,0]$, $v_b=[0,1,0,0]$, $v_c=[0,0,1,0]$, $v_d=[0,0,0,1]$.

The Jordan form $>J$ of this matrix is given by:
$$
J=S^{-1}AS
$$
with (from [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordan%20form%7B%7B0%2C%200%2C%20-1%2C0%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C-2%2C%200%2C%203%7D%2C%20%7B1%2C%200%2C%200%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C%200%2C%200%2C-2%7D%7D))

$$
J=\begin{bmatrix}
-2&1&0&0\\
0&-2&0&0\\
0&0&-i&0\\
0&0&0&i
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
S=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&-i&i\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&1\\
0&1/3&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

this means that the eigenvalue $\lambda_1=-2$ has an eigenvector 
$$\nu_1=[0,1,0,0]^T=v_b:$$ 
(as we can see from the third condition),
and a **generalized** eigenvector 
$$\nu_2=\left[0,0,0,\frac{1}{3}\right]^T= \frac{1}{3}v_d$$.

The other eigenvalues and eigenvectors are:
$$
\lambda_2= i \qquad \nu_2=[i,0,1,0]^T
$$

$$
\lambda_3= -i \qquad \nu_3=[-i,0,-1,0]^T
$$

If you know the components of the vectors of the basis $\mathbf V$ in another basis you can express the eigenvectors in this other basis.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Now I see the sign error! Thank you!! I edit.